# splash screen is not displayed everytime app started in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I hv made an app for ios 4.2(IPhone 4)...it's working fine with just 1 problem.
it is not displaying splash screen when app runs from background.
splash screen is visible onle 1st time when app is launched
I hv tried UIApplicationExistsOnSuspend (true) but problem is not solved for me.
plz friend any help..jst note that i m using ios 4.2.

Comment: Note that Apple discourages splash screens.

Comment: this is what i need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling your splash screen method from within the 
`applicationWillEnterForeground` delegate method.

Comment: can u give me some code ...what should i write in this metod..plz!!

Comment: How are you currently displaying the splash screen? Is the code for that contained in one method? Just try exactly the same thing. Note that the applicationWillEnterForeground method will get called automatically (There is probably a stub for it generated for you), so put the same code (or a call to that code) in there.